# Definition List Formatting Not Working As Intended

Tags: html, css, wordpress, formatting, wordpress-theming

I learned more about definition list by trying to duplicate a product page that I love.

Added the    tags properly and noticed they had some natural styling to them.

I found this code on google and added it to my theme's custom.css file and it's not changing anything.

```
dt {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
  dd {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0.5em 0;
  }
```

Can anyone PLEASE tell me why?

THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Some code would be nice, copy your code to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and set up example. Probably it's getting overridden by defaults style try adding !important to css properties.

```
dt {
    font-weight: bold important;
    text-decoration: underline important;
  }
  dd {
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 0 0.5em 0 important;
  }
```

This will override any css properties, but you should use it just for testing.